# Missing all users startup folder, is there a way to make an active one?

Tags: startup, windows-7

The all users profile startup programs folder is missing under this path. The workstations are running windows 7. 
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Is there a way to create one that works in this paths place?

It may have been removed by group policy, but until we locate that I am looking for an alternative fix.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try typing `shell:startup`in the start menu search bar, does anything come up? This should be the users startup folder.

Otherwise there is a great article located [here](http://windowstipsandfixes.blogspot.com/2007/09/restore-startup-folder.html) on how to recover your "Startup"

Comment: Thank you, this is a huge help, I'll try this out today!

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting the All Users startup programs via the registry by adding a new String value to one of the following keys. (The string value should contain the path to the program you want to run upon startup)

32 bit:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce

64 bit:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce